# C# Task.Wait Freezin

Tags: c#

I have a winform when you click a button it calls a task wait function however it is freezing i'm not sure why.

```
private async Task GetsData()
        {

            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

            IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("mydb");

            var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mydata");

            using (var cursor = await collection.Find(new 
BsonDocument()).ToCursorAsync())
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(doc.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GetsData().Wait();
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            }
        }
```

how can `i stop it from freezing?

Comment: What is freezing exactly? Have you set breakpoints to know what could be the problem?

Comment: Does you mean it freezes the GUI?

Comment: Where you have a call to `Task.Wait()`?

Comment: Task.Waiit is blocking, while awaiting it is not. This method looks ok, the problem would be on the calling side.

Comment: The task.wait is in a button click event that calls this function.

Comment: i've added my button click event

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes

Comment: I added a background worker and made the button call the backgroudnworker and it worked. I guess it was trying to update the UI or something on a different thread? It is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Wait()` is a blocking action. It will block the GUI thread waiting for the Task/Promise returned from `GetsData()` to resolve. Meanwhile, async scheduling in a WinForms app will be scheduled against the GUI thread by the SynchronizationContext. Since the GUI thread is blocked by the `Wait()`, these units of work cannot execute in order to resolve the Task which results in a deadlock.

When using async-await, it is best to use all the way through your code. It is very easy to end up with a deadlock when doing any thread blocking with async-await. Stephen Cleary has some great articles around this when async-await was first introduced.

To resolve, there are a few potential paths but the simplest for this case is likely to turn your event handler in to an `async void` method and `await` the `GetsData()` call instead of using `Wait()`. Event handlers are the one generally accepted place `async void` is ideal to use.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: I will give your way a shot since it looks simpler and easier to read than my solution, I just added a backgroundworker thank you